# lodash function does not return a single object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, map-function

I use `lodash` map function in a react app in order to handle an array of objects that is returned as a response from a server. That works well when the response is indeed an array of objects. Sometimes though the response is just a single object. In that case, my code does not work.

```
render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const simplifiedData = data && _.get(data, ['Soap:Envelope', 'Soap:Body', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ItemCharacteristics']);
    const beautifiedData = _.map(simplifiedData, simple => _.reduce(simple, (r, value, key) => ({
        ...r,
        [key]: value['_text']
      }), {}));
   
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    beautifiedData.map((product, i) => {
                        return (
                                <ItemDetailsCard
                                    key={i}
                                    itemNo={product.Item_No}
                                    code={product.Code}
                                    Description_2={product.Description_2}
                                    GrossRequirement={product.GrossRequirement}
                                    ScheduledRcpt={product.ScheduledRcpt}
                                    ExpectedDate={product.ExpectedRcptDate}
                                    Inventory={product.Inventory}
                                    ProjAvailBalance={product.ProjAvailBalance}
                                />


                        );
                    })
                }
```

Here is an example of single object response:

```
{  
   "Soap:Envelope":{  
  "_attributes":{  
     "xmlns:Soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  },
  "Soap:Body":{  
     "ReadMultiple_Result":{  
        "_attributes":{  
           "xmlns":"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/itemcharacteristics"
        },
        "ReadMultiple_Result":{  
           "ItemCharacteristics":{  
              "Key":{  
                 "_text":"44;GRUAAAJ7/zAAMQAtADAAMAAxADUAAAACewMwADUAMQ==9;4258681930;"
              },
              "Item_No":{  
                 "_text":"01-0015"
              },
              "Code":{  
                 "_text":"051"
              },
              "Description_2":{  
                 "_text":"ΜΑΥΡΟ"
              },
              "GrossRequirement":{  
                 "_text":"0"
              },
              "ScheduledRcpt":{  
                 "_text":"0"
              },
              "ExpectedRcptDate":{  
                 "_text":"0001-01-01"
              },
              "Inventory":{  
                 "_text":"0"
              },
              "ProjAvailBalance":{  
                 "_text":"0"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
```

}

and an example of an array of objects response:

```
{  
   "Soap:Envelope":{  
  "_attributes":{  
     "xmlns:Soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  },
  "Soap:Body":{  
     "ReadMultiple_Result":{  
        "_attributes":{  
           "xmlns":"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/itemcharacteristics"
        },
        "ReadMultiple_Result":{  
           "ItemCharacteristics":[  
              {  
                 "Key":{  
                    "_text":"44;GRUAAAJ7/zAAMQAtADAAMAAwADgAAAACewMxADcAMg==9;4258681780;"
                 },
                 "Item_No":{  
                    "_text":"01-0008"
                 },
                 "Code":{  
                    "_text":"172"
                 },
                 "Description_2":{  
                    "_text":"ΜΠΛΕ"
                 },
                 "GrossRequirement":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ScheduledRcpt":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ExpectedRcptDate":{  
                    "_text":"0001-01-01"
                 },
                 "Inventory":{  
                    "_text":"41.1"
                 },
                 "ProjAvailBalance":{  
                    "_text":"41.1"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "Key":{  
                    "_text":"44;GRUAAAJ7/zAAMQAtADAAMAAwADgAAAACewM2ADIAOA==9;4258681790;"
                 },
                 "Item_No":{  
                    "_text":"01-0008"
                 },
                 "Code":{  
                    "_text":"628"
                 },
                 "Description_2":{  
                    "_text":"ΧΡΥΣΟ"
                 },
                 "GrossRequirement":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ScheduledRcpt":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ExpectedRcptDate":{  
                    "_text":"0001-01-01"
                 },
                 "Inventory":{  
                    "_text":"40.2"
                 },
                 "ProjAvailBalance":{  
                    "_text":"40.2"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "Key":{  
                    "_text":"44;GRUAAAJ7/zAAMQAtADAAMAAwADgAAAACewM3ADAAMw==9;4258681800;"
                 },
                 "Item_No":{  
                    "_text":"01-0008"
                 },
                 "Code":{  
                    "_text":"703"
                 },
                 "Description_2":{  
                    "_text":"ΓΚΡΕΝΑ"
                 },
                 "GrossRequirement":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ScheduledRcpt":{  
                    "_text":"0"
                 },
                 "ExpectedRcptDate":{  
                    "_text":"0001-01-01"
                 },
                 "Inventory":{  
                    "_text":"34.1"
                 },
                 "ProjAvailBalance":{  
                    "_text":"34.1"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Could someone provide the logic of handling a response that is a single object?

Comment: Could you provide examples of multiple and single object responses? I assume it is JSON

Comment: So your `simplifiedData` is what might be a single object or an array ?

Comment: @HerrSerker Yes of course, I edited my question and provided examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using `lodash` in your code, since I see you use underscore expression. In that case, try to use `_.castArray` on your state data to ensure you always use array in rendering:

```
const beautifiedData = _.map(_.castArray(simplifiedData), simple => _.reduce(simple, (r, value, key) => ({
    ...r,
    [key]: value['_text']
}), {}));
```

Better yet, you can check and preprocess your server response before updating state to ensure `state.data` only store array, regardless of number of items in response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `isArray` method.

There is a [native one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) in the `Array` object or you can use the [`Lodash` one](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isArray) since you are using that.

```
const simplifiedData = data && _.get(data, ['Soap:Envelope', 'Soap:Body', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ItemCharacteristics']);
const simplifiedDataArray = Array.isArray(simplifiedData) ? simplifiedData  : [simplifiedData]
// or in Lodash
// const simplifiedDataArray = _.isArray(simplifiedData) ? simplifiedData  : [simplifiedData]
```

---

If you want to go the `Lodash` way though there is method for doing just that, namely [`castArray`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#castArray) which will wrap anything you pass to it to an array if it is not one already.

```
const simplifiedData = data && _.get(data, ['Soap:Envelope', 'Soap:Body', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ItemCharacteristics']);
const simplifiedDataArray = _.castArray(simplifiedData);
```